# Display thumbnailPhoto from Active Directory in PHP

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap, adldap

I've set up a system to display everyone's name, email address and phone number from Active Directory however I can't get the 'thumbailPhoto' to work.

I have searched around on the internet but haven't been able to find if this is possible or at the very least what format is returned from Active Directory.

I am currently using the adldap class so if it is possible to use this that would be ideal.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

I can retrieve the data in the thumbnailPhoto attribute and if I dump them straight to the browser I get something like this:

> ÿØÿàJFIFððÿá
>   PExifII*bh~†(2Ži‡¢XCanonCanon EOS 5D Mark
>   IIIðð2013:05:19 17:35:31š‚à‚è"ˆ'ˆ 0230ð’
>   ’ ’ (’0’8’ ’ ’@‘’11’’11 0100
>   ÿÿ¢H¢P¢¤¤¤¤  2013:04:17
>   11:44:522013:04:17 11:44:52H¹o@B¬  †
>   è»dnäWµ˜:Ì¦®(¶’
>   HHÿØÿàJFIFÿÛC    $.'
>   ",#(7),01444'9=82<.342ÿÛC 
>   2!!22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222ÿÀ–d"ÿÄ
>   ÿÄµ}!1AQa"q2‘¡#B±ÁRÑð$3br‚
>   %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyzƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š’“”•–—˜™š¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª²³´µ¶·¸¹ºÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚáâãäåæçèéêñòóôõö÷øùúÿÄ
>   ÿÄµw!1AQaq"2B‘¡±Á #3RðbrÑ $4á%ñ&'()*

That isn't all of it but it is a very long string, I am presuming is some sort of binary string?

Comment: I assume that you can retrieve the content of the 'thumbnailPhoto'. Have you analysed what image-format the content is?

Comment: I have added a snippet of what is returned. In regards to image format I don't know what Active Directory does to the image when a user adds one. I don't know if it remains in the format they upload or if it is processed in some way.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This seems to be a JPEG-File, so you should be able to send that data together with the appropriate mime-type to the browser. It should be possible to output that image with something like:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($imageString); ?>"/>
```

But it might also be possible to save files of **any** image format into that `thumbnailPhoto` attribute. Therefore, I would put the content into a temporary file that will then be served directly from the server. You will need to pass the file through `finfo` to get the correct mime-type.

So you might do something like this:

```
$tempFile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'image');
file_put_contents($tempFile, $imageString);
$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mime  = explode(';', $finfo->file($tempFile));
echo '<img src="data:' . $mime[0] . ';base64,' . base64_encode($imageString) . '"/>';
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I tweaked the code slightly as I knew it would be an image but this definitely solved my problem and works great.

Comment: For what its worth, I used this solution to resolve mime type, but was able to skip writing to file by using `$finfo->buffer($binary)`

Answer (score 6):

Try the code below. It is an adaptation of the answer above.

`<?php
    $result = ldap_search($ad , $dn , $filter, $attributes);
    $aduser = ldap_get_attributes($ad, ldap_first_entry($ad,$result));
?>`

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($aduser['thumbnailPhoto'][0]); ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

when you store the photo data into ldap i.e. "jpegphoto" attribute it should be done by using encode base64. 
Reading the attribute is already decoded on fly. Hence I would use something less modified code

```
$tempFile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'image');
file_put_contents($tempFile, $imageString);
$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mime  = explode(';', $finfo->file($tempFile));
header("Content-Type: $mime");
echo $imageString;
```

This is direct php image write example 
you can directly use it under tag img i.e.

```
<img src="example.php" />
```