# PHP - get LDAP thumbnailphoto attribute to display in HTML

Tags: php, encoding, ldap, base64

I use a php script to query our LDAP and output the results to HTML - now I also want to get the **thumbnailphoto** but I struggle to convert the encoded image.

The image data looks like this:
[image: thumbnailphoto]

```
$data = $ldapResults[$i]['thumbnailphoto'][0];
echo "<td>" .$data . "</td>";
```

I found this post @[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16937863/display-thumbnailphoto-from-active-directory-in-php) but I can't get it to work.

What do I need to do to display the image properly?

Thank you.

Comment: What does not work for you with the examples posted in the other question? Please be aware that you cannot directly output binary image data into a `td` element.

Comment: you can also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070603/php-recreate-and-display-an-image-from-binary-data) is quite clear and you should know the type of the image

Comment: this: echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($data); ?>" />';
gives me the following html:
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($data); ?>" />
how do I need to modify this?

Comment: use this code: ```echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($data) . '"/>'```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working with FILEINFO as described in the [link above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16937863/display-thumbnailphoto-from-active-directory-in-php) after testing some more. Thank you.