# how to get and display photo from ldap

Tags: python-3.x, ldap

I'm using ldap3.
I can connect and read all attributes without any issue, but I don't know how to display the photo of the attribute thumbnailPhoto.
If I `print(conn.entries[0].thumbnailPhoto)` I get a bunch of binary values like `b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF.....'`.
I have to display it on a bottle web page. So I have to put this value in a jpeg or png file.
How can I do that?

Comment: Please provide more information: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to save the raw byte value in a file and open it with a picture editor. The photo is probably a jpeg, but it can be in any format.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at my answer at [Display thumbnailPhoto from Active Directory in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16937863/display-thumbnailphoto-from-active-directory-in-php/16948219#16948219). It's especially for PHP but the concept is the same for Python.

basically it's about either using the base64 encoded raw-data as data-stream or actually using a temporary file that is serverd (or used to determine the mime-type)