# Pull AD Photo using PHP

Tags: php, html, active-directory

I am trying to return a user's AD photo along with their name and job title. I can pull any of the text fields ok but it errors when i try to pull the "thumbnailPhoto" attribute. Admittedly I am using a template that I found however i'm confused how most attributes seem to work apart from the photo.

This is the error that I currently get when trying to run the below code

`Notice: Undefined index: thumbnailphoto in C:\xampp\htdocs\visitor\ldap-test.php on line 23`

Any help would be appreciated.

```
    <?php
// -------------- CHANGE VARIABLES TO SUIT YOUR ENVIRONMENT  --------------
//LDAP server address
$server = "ldap://192.168.1.55";
//domain user to connect to LDAP
$user = "user.name@mydomain.local";
//user password
$psw = "password";
//FQDN path where search will be performed. OU - organizational unit / DC - domain component
$dn = "OU=Accounts,OU=My Company,DC=mydomain,DC=com";
//Search query. CN - common name (CN=* will return all objects)
$search = "CN=*";                    
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo "<h2>php LDAP query test</h2>";
// connecting to LDAP server
$ds=ldap_connect($server);
$r=ldap_bind($ds, $user , $psw); 
// performing search
$sr=ldap_search($ds, $dn, $search);
$data = ldap_get_entries($ds, $sr);    
echo "Found " . $data["count"] . " entries";
for ($i=0; $i<$data["count"]; $i++) {
 echo "<h4><strong>Common Name: </strong>" . $data[$i]["cn"][0] . "</h4><br />";
 echo "<strong>Distinguished Name: </strong>" . $data[$i]["dn"] . "<br />";
 //checking if discription exists 
 if (isset($data[$i]["description"][0])) 
 echo "<strong>Desription: </strong>" . $data[$i]["description"][0] . "<br />";
 else 
 echo "<strong>Description not set</strong><br />";
 //checking if email exists
 if (isset($data[$i]["mail"][0]))
 echo "<strong>Email: </strong>" . $data[$i]["mail"][0] . "<br /><hr />";
 else 
 echo "<strong>Email not set</strong><br /><hr />";
 }
 // close connection
 ldap_close($ds);
?>
```

Comment: `...it errors when i try to...` What's the error?

Comment: "Notice: Undefined index: thumbnailPhoto in C:\xampp\htdocs\visitor\ldap-test.php on line 23"

I am replacing the 'cn' part with thumbnailPhoto. I have done some research and I will need to put it in an image tag etc but I am expecting to at least see the hex values at this stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run this code example:

```
<?php

// -------------- CHANGE VARIABLES TO SUIT YOUR ENVIRONMENT  --------------
//LDAP server address
$server = "ldap://192.168.1.55";
//domain user to connect to LDAP
$user = "user.name@mydomain.local";
//user password
$psw = "password";
//FQDN path where search will be performed. OU - organizational unit / DC - domain component
$dn = "OU=Accounts,OU=My Company,DC=mydomain,DC=com";
//Search query. CN - common name (CN=* will return all objects)
$search = "CN=*";
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

echo "<h2>php LDAP query test</h2>";
// connecting to LDAP server
$ds = ldap_connect($server);
$r = ldap_bind($ds, $user , $psw);
// performing search
$sr = ldap_search($ds, $dn, $search);
$data = ldap_get_entries($ds, $sr);

echo "Found " . $data["count"] . " entries";

for ($i = 0; $i < $data["count"]; $i++) {
    echo "<h4><strong>Common Name: </strong>" . $data[$i]["cn"][0] . "</h4><br />";
    echo "<strong>Distinguished Name: </strong>" . $data[$i]["dn"] . "<br />";

    // Check if user photo exists
    if (isset($data[$i]["thumbnailphoto"]) && isset($data[$i]["thumbnailphoto"][0])) {
        echo "<strong>Photo in Base64: </strong>" . base64_encode($data[$i]["thumbnailphoto"][0]) . "<br />";
    }
    else {
        echo "<strong>Photo not set</strong><br />";
    }

    // Checking if discription exists 
    if (isset($data[$i]["description"][0])) {
        echo "<strong>Desription: </strong>" . $data[$i]["description"][0] . "<br />";
    }
    else {
        echo "<strong>Description not set</strong><br />";
    }

    // Checking if email exists
    if (isset($data[$i]["mail"][0])){
        echo "<strong>Email: </strong>" . $data[$i]["mail"][0] . "<br /><hr />";
    }
    else {
        echo "<strong>Email not set</strong><br /><hr />";
    }
}

// close connection
ldap_close($ds);
?>
```

The problem should be that you check if `$data[$i]["thumbnailphoto"][0]` is set while you should check the `$data[$i]["thumbnailphoto"]` first.

Then you can read this question [Display thumbnailPhoto from Active Directory in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16937863/display-thumbnailphoto-from-active-directory-in-php) and continue coding to display the image.

Comment: Had to change the attributes in your snippet to have a lowercase p in "thumbnailPhoto" but after doing that it worked. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, I forgot that LDAP returns lowercase.